# Need help in identifying a font

Tags: fonts

I have been looking for, and have had trouble finding the following font. Anyone care to help identify? Appreciated.

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  This looks to me a lot like `cmss` -- Computer Modern sans serif -- with `cmssbx` for the bold.  (I can't easily check, because all my reference books are currently stored in boxes.)

Comment: You might like to review the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919/15036).  Do they help?  If so perhaps your question is a duplicate.